# How to save machine state without hibernating?

Tags: kernel, hibernate

I wonder is it possible to capture the state of the machine without actually hibernating? The goal would be to make a "backup state", so if the system crashes, one could boot directly to a session with all the windows opened, all the tabs in the browser restored etc.

I think it might not be doable -- saving a snapshot of the memory, then changing the data on the hard drive, and then again restoring the snapshot would result in broken file descriptors etc. For example, a process opened a file before the snapshot was taken, and when the snapshot was restored, the file is no longer existing.

But maybe there is an ingenious way of solving that?

Comment: Good question. For this I use VirtualBox :)

Comment: I use vbox for Windows, but maybe I should reverse the situation. I am having a lot of problems with my Lenovo and 12.04 (freezes, crashes, system not waking up etc., pretty randomly).

Comment: @EvandroSilva Do you do all your work in VirtualBox? Isn't Ubuntu installed under VirtualBox much slower that one installed directly on the machine?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning these days, I use dual boot

Comment: @EvandroSilva How does dual boot help you save the state of machine in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to keep all of the mounted block filesystems completely untouched (that is, mounted only in read-only mode, as an ext4 journal will be modified even without any changes for example), and unmount others (eg NFS) before freezing, then yes.

You can use the kernel parameters `noresume` and `resume=` to specify whether you want to reboot into your frozen state or not.

The sequence would be:

- To snapshot, suspend to disk, boot your system without resuming (`noresume`) or another system altogether (like a livecd), copy the swap partition elsewhere, then reboot with the correct `resume=` and use your system.
- To go back to the frozen state, boot again with `noresume` or from another system, copy the swap partition back, then reboot with the correct `resume=` again.

I wouldn't recommend this though. Virtualization offers a much safer and tested way to achieve your results with fewer caveats.

Comment: By virtualization, you mean something like VirtualBox, right? But isn't Ubuntu installed under VirtualBox much slower that one installed directly on the machine?